# Security issue with dynamic script tags

Tags: javascript, security, json

This [flickr blog post](http://code.flickr.com/blog/2009/03/18/building-fast-client-side-searches/) discusses the thought behind their latest improvements to the people selector autocomplete.

One problem they had to overcome was how to parse and otherwise handle so much data (i.e., all your contacts) client-side. They tried getting XML and JSON via AJAX, but found it too slow. They then had this to say about loading the data via a dynamically generated script tag (with callback function):

> ### JSON and Dynamic Script Tags: Fast but Insecure
>
> Working with the theory that large
>   string manipulation was the problem
>   with the last approach, we switched
>   from using Ajax to instead fetching
>   the data using a dynamically generated
>   script tag. This means that the
>   contact data was never treated as
>   string, and was instead executed as
>   soon as it was downloaded, just like
>   any other JavaScript file. The
>   difference in performance was
>   shocking: 89ms to parse 10,000
>   contacts (a reduction of 3 orders of
>   magnitude), while the smallest case of
>   172 contacts only took 6ms. The parse
>   time per contact actually decreased
>   the larger the list became. This
>   approach looked perfect, except for
>   one thing: in order for this JSON to
>   be executed, we had to wrap it in a
>   callback method. **Since it’s executable
>   code, any website in the world could
>   use the same approach to download a
>   Flickr member’s contact list.** This was
>   a deal breaker. (emphasis mine)

Could someone please go into the exact security risk here (perhaps with a sample exploit)? How is loading a given file via the "src" attribute in a script tag different from loading that file via an AJAX call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a good question and this exact sort of exploit was once used to steal contact lists from gmail.

Whenever a browser fetches data from a domain, it send across any cookie data that the site has set. This cookie data can then used to authenticate the user, and fetch any specific user data.

For example, when you load a new stackoverflow.com page, your browser sends your cookie data to stackoverflow.com. Stackoverflow uses that data to determine who you are, and shows the appropriate data for you.

The same is true for anything else that you load from a domain, including CSS and Javascript files.

The security vulnerability that Flickr faced was that any website could embed this javascript file hosted on Flickr's servers. Your Flickr cookie data would then be sent over as part of the request (since the javascript was hosted on flickr.com), and Flickr would generate a javascript document containing the sensitive data. The malicious site would then be able to get access to the data that was loaded.

Here is the exploit that was used to steal google contacts, which may make it more clear than my explanation above:
http://blogs.zdnet.com/Google/?p=434

Answer (score 6):

If I was to put an HTML page on my website like this:

```
<script src="http://www.flickr.com/contacts.js"></script>
<script> // send the contact data to my server with AJAX </script>
```

Assuming contacts.js uses the session to know which contacts to send, I would now have a copy of your contacts.

However if the contacts are sent via JSON, I can't request them from my HTML page, because it would be a cross-domain AJAX request, which isn't allowed.  I can't request the page from my server either, because I wouldn't have your session ID.

Answer (score 0):

In plain english:

Unauthorised computer code (Javascript) running on people's computers is not allowed to get data from anywhere but the site on which it runs - browsers are obliged to enforce this rule.

There is no corresponding restriction on where code can be sourced from, so if you embed data in code any website the user visits can employ the user's credentials to obtain the user's data.